# What is wrong with my IF logic?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am writing a Javascript and dont know how to form the loop

```
    if (value < 25){
                    $(selector).css({ 'background': 'Red' });
                } else if (value > 25 && value < 75){
                    $(selector).css({ 'background': 'Orange' });
                }else{
                    $(selector).css({ 'background': 'LightGreen' });
                }
```

else if error--> Unmatched else no if defined 
Where am I going wrong. Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with C# and ASP.NET? What's the error? What does this have to do with AND?

Comment: What's the problem/question? What does this has to do with `c#`, `asp.net` and `asp` (tags you have used)?

Comment: There is no loop in the code you have provided.

Comment: right now, that code works http://jsfiddle.net/VEe8Z/

Comment: @Mano : Have you corrected the code in your question? It looks correct now. Are you still getting any error?

Comment: @Mano Just a note: The background is going to be green in the event that `value` is equal to 25. It's not less than 25, and it's not greater than 25, so it will fall into the `else` statement. Just a guess, but I bet that's not your desired behavior.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(value > 25) && (value < 75){
```

should be

```
if(value > 25 && value < 75){
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
else if ((value > 25) && (value < 75))
```

not

```
else if (value > 25) && (value < 75)
```

**EDIT**

This is quite common in programming languages. You have to enclose all the conditions in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
                if (value < 25){
                    $(selector).css({ 'background': 'Red' });
                } else if (value > 25 && value < 75){
                    $(selector).css({ 'background': 'Orange' });
                }else{
                    $(selector).css({ 'background': 'LightGreen' });
                }
```

You need to have parentheses around the whole if block.